# Error in event handler: ReferenceError: window is not defined chrome extension with manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am using manifest version 3 for chrome extension this error I face in background js :
**Error in event handler: ReferenceError: window is not defined chrome extension with manifest v3**

"manifest_version":3,
"permissions":["contextMenus","storage", "activeTab","tabs","scripting","webRequest"],

`var posLeft = ( window.width - winWidth ) / 2 ;`

Comment: ManifestV3 extension uses a service worker so it doesn't have DOM or `window`. Why do you need window.width in the background script?

Comment: @wOxxOm I want to set chrome.windows.create open in center in browser screen, So first i want to get window.width then I minus   chrome.windows width

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ManifestV3 extension uses a service worker so it doesn't have DOM or `window`.

- Use [chrome.windows.getCurrent](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-getCurrent) to get the size/position of the current browser window.
- Use [chrome.system.display.getInfo](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/system_display/#method-getInfo) (since Chrome 94) to get the display's size/metrics.

Comment: i'd like to get a global function in background by name using `window["funcname"]` but no window object

Comment: See [Using \`window\` globals in ManifestV3 service worker background script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73785852)

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to access window object in background.js as it is a service worker you won't have access to window object , but you may try self as it will have all the properties of window object
in `background.js` try

```
console.log(self,"self")
var window = window ?? self;
```

`Note: if you are using Vite or Webpack this might work`

[image]

Comment: No. I don't think this is window object, but rather self=this=chrome service worker

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 3):

Well for others who may look here for that error message in a similar context, I got the same error when neglecting to make the `window` object accessible at runtime rather than at the time that the injected function is dynamically being readied for injection into a particular tab by the v3 background script.

In order to get dynamically injected from a v3 background script, the tab specific object (in this case `window`) needs to be included inside the function being passed, as in the following anonymous function case:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: currentTab.id },
    func: () => window.history.back()
  });
```

if `window.history.back` is provided as the value for `func` then obviously it will not be known or available to the background script and the same error message will ensue.

This is already described indeed in the docs.

Comment: FWIW, this code works in ManifestV3 service worker because the function never runs in the context of the service worker, it is serialized as a string, which get injected into the tab.