# Using `window` globals in ManifestV3 service worker background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I'm working on a Manifest v3 browser extension where I need to identify the browser in which the extension is currently running from the backgroundScript. Since ManifestV3 extension uses a service worker, it doesn't have DOM or `window`. So I'm not able to use `window.navigator.userAgent`.

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194718/6908282) which talks about how to gets window height and width information, but I couldn't find any other information to fetch the userAgent of the browser.

Is this possible?

Comment: Get the `navigator` object from a content script and send that to the service worker with [`sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple) or you could use [`getPlatformInfo`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getPlatformInfo) in a service worker event if you think that could work for you

Comment: you can use both **navigator.userAgent** or **navigator.userAgentData.brands**.  Better the 2nd 'cause the 1st is going to be depracated.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm, thank worked. Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Neutral globals

Things like `navigator` aren't specific to visual representation of a window.
**Just omit `window.` and read it directly:**

- `navigator`
- `navigator.userAgent`
- `atob`
- `fetch`

### Window-specific globals

Things specific to user interaction or visual/aural representation like DOM or AudioContext, or those that may show a prompt for user permissions.

Not available in a worker. The workaround is to split that part of the code into the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) and use messaging to pass the data back and forth. It can be `chrome.runtime` [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) or  `navigator.serviceWorker` messaging, which supports binary data like Uint8Array, Blob, Map, etc.

### Aliases for `window`

Use them instead of `window` for code clarity or if a local variable is named just as a global property.

- Built-in `globalThis` (Chrome/ium 71+, FF 65+) and `self`

  These are worker-compatible aliases for the global scope. Note that a JS library you're loading may redefine them theoretically, but that'd be really weird and abnormal.
- Self-made `global`

  The most reliable method, but you'll have to add `'use strict'` only inside an IIFE not globally.
  This is already offered by bundlers like webpack.
  Here's how you can replicate it yourself:

  ```
  const global = (function(){
    if (!this) throw "Don't add 'use strict' globally, use it inside IIFE/functions";
    return this;
  })();
  ```