# 'prefers-color-scheme' detection in Chrome background service worker

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Is there an alternative method to detect `'prefers-color-scheme'` since `window.matchMedia` fails in the background service worker?

```js
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
// Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Comment: Do it in the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using \`window\` globals in ManifestV3 service worker background script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778202/using-window-globals-in-manifestv3-service-worker-background-script)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. I was wondering if there was another method to detect `'prefers-color-scheme'` i.e. without using `window.matchMedia`.

Comment: It's the only javascript method.